# VerticalLayout dynamically hiding visibility

Tags: sapui5

I was wondering whats the best way around dynamically hiding some menu items. At the moment I have 6 items just in a matrix layout row. I want to have 3 items aligned left and 3 items alligned right. If one of the items is set to not visible I want it to move accross. I've done something similiar in a horizontal layout and setting the visibility to hidden. I was wondering if this would work with a vertical layout? Having trouble trying to figure out exactly how I would do it as I'm quite new to UI5 xml css and javscript. Any help would be great.

Also I'm having one other issue unrelated to this, I cant seem to bind my json model to my xml fragment, if I use the same code on my normal xml view it prints out the model data. But on my fragment it just prints it like {person>/fullName} any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Belongs to your second question.

- Maybe your binding was quoted on copy and paste? Check the native XML Code.
- If no data are shown (not "{person>/fullName}"), add dependent to connect the models of your view

  `var oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(sFragment, "fragmentName", this);
  oView.addDependent(oFragment);`